# Android Kiosk Mode - getting started

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

Here are my requirements:

- Run my Android app on an Android tablet
- Full screen
- Automatic launch on power up
- No back button or any other navigation visible
- User cannot quit the app

So these requirement all point to Kiosk mode.

I have searched for programming solutions, but since I am reasonably new to the world of Android development, I find the solutions quite hard to follow / understand.

I also searched for off-the-shelf solutions, but the ones I found seem (a) way too powerful for what I want, and (b) quite expensive (pay per month plans).

I know this is a very open-ended question but can anyone point me in the right direction to a simple solution?

For off-the-shelf, I don’t mind paying a one-off price if it is not too much, but I would prefer to solve this programmatically.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Garrett

Comment: Reminder that [asking for recommendations is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). A better question would be attempting a programmatic solution and showing where you are stuck. StackOverflow can't help with build vs buy problems as there are too many unknowns and assumptions.

Comment: Okay, point noted thanks